# Can I remap port numbers for cloud compute instances such as from port 502 to 1502

Tags: google-compute-engine, remap, tcp-port

I have some IoT devices that uses modbustcp on port 502. I have a communications solution running on windows that I would like to use on some google compute instances.
Since ports below 1024 is nogo unless being elevated (sudo) then I have been looking for a way inside Googles cloud configuration tools to remap then incoming requests to different port numbers so that my code can listen on port 1502 instead.
Is any such port remapping available in the Google compute configurations?

Comment: authbind was the solution.
I installed it on the server and added the byport 502 (don't have the link to the explanation site anymore)
I can now start the application having .listen(502) with "authbind nodejs app.js"